# Bounded operator and dense sets

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $A : E \rightarrow E$ be a linear operator, and $E$ a (typically infinite-dimensional) Banach space. Suppose that $S$ is a collection of norm 1 elements of $E$ spanning a dense subspace of $E$.

1. Does $||Ax|| \leq C ||x||$ for all $x \in S$ imply that $A$ is bounded ?

2.(EDITED) Does $||x|| \leq c ||Ax||$ for all $x \in S$ and $A$ bounded, injective imply that $A$ is bounded below ?

Clearly this would be true if $S$ *were dense itself*, but since it only spans a dense subspace I'm not so sure.

Reason for the edit : 
Without those hypotheses, the answer is clearly no to point 2 : as in David's answer, take a Hamel basis $e_n$ and let $Ae_n=e_n$ and let $Ax=0$ for any $x \notin span(e_n)$.

Comment: I think this should work to show 1. is false: In $\ell_2$, extend the unit vectors, $(e_i)$, to a Hamel basis $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ of $\ell_2$. Note $I$ must be uncountable. Define $A$ so that $Ae_i=e_i$. Define $A$ on the other elements of $(f_\alpha)$ so that it is unbounded.

Comment: I agree with your proof. Concerning point 2, I am changing a bit the hypothesis (sorry to change the original question).

Comment: Even if $S$ is dense in $E$, 1. does not hold true. Just proceed as in David's comment, start with any dense and linearly independent sequence $(z_i)\subset\ell_2$ instead of $(e_i)$.

Comment: @Etienne Noted, thank you

Comment: Even with the additional hypothesis that $A$ is bounded, 2. need not hold. Consider $\ell^2$, and $A e_{2k} = e_{2k}$, $A e_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2^{k+5}}e_{2k+1} - e_{2k}$. If $S$ was dense in the unit sphere, it would, of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for this example ! If you or David Mitra make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidMitra Care to make an answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer Done. I wonder if an example can be made without the heavy machinery (i.e, the Axiom of Choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no" to your first question:

In $\ell_2$, extend the unit vectors, $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$, to a Hamel basis $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ of $\ell_2$. For $i\in\Bbb N$,  define $Ae_i=e_i$. Define $A$ on the other elements of $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ so that it is unbounded  (for instance, take $(h_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ a sequence from $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ disjoint from $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ and map $h_i$ to $i\cdot h_i $).  Note $I$ must be uncountable; hence this can be done.

The answer to your second question is "no" as well, as Daniel Fischer's comment in the original post shows.